# Why does my Python program only allow for a certain sequence of inputs?

Tags: python

in this program the user must enter the length of the sequence and then enter a word in each of the following sequences. the python program needs to output the number of pairs of adjacent words that begin with the same first letter. my code below performs this well until you enter an input such as these

Example 1:
input:

```
Length of sequence: 2
1st word: blue
2nd word: black
```

Expected Output:

```
Pairs of adjacent words: 1
```

output by my code:

```
pairs of adjacent words: 0
```

Example 2:
input:

```
Length of sequence: 3
1st word: what
2nd word: who
3rd word: when
```

Expected Output:

```
Pairs of adjacent words: 2
```

output by my code:

```
pairs of adjacent words: 0
```

Here is my code:

```
n= int(input("Enter the length of the sequence:\n"))
current_letter = 'a'
count = 0
pairs = 0

for i in range (0,n):
    word = input('Enter word '+ str(i+1)+':\n')
    first_letter = word[:1]
    
    if current_letter == first_letter:
        count = count + 1
    else:
        if count > 0:
            pairs = pairs + 1
        count = 0
        current_letter = first_letter

print('Number of pairs of adjacent words with same first letter: '+ str(pairs))
```

> Example of correct output:

```
Enter the length of the sequence:5
Enter word 1: how
Enter word 2: here
Enter word 3: who
Enter word 4: when
Enter word 5: you
Number of pairs of adjacent words with the same first letter: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, and did a really good job with the logic. Making a couple of simple tweaks makes the code work.

```
n= int(input("Enter the length of the sequence:\n"))
current_letter = 'a'
pairs = 0

for i in range (0,n):
    word = input('Enter word '+ str(i+1)+':\n')
    first_letter = word[:1]
    if(current_letter == first_letter):
        pairs += 1
    current_letter = first_letter

print('Number of pairs of adjacent words with same first letter: '+ str(pairs))
```

Keep it up!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you put `current_letter = 'a'` on the second line to test your code. But when you run your program you want to set `current_letter` to the actual current letter. To initialize `current_letter`, I would do a single `input()` call before the loop starts. This lets you get the current letter from the first word. Then you simply run your for loop one less time.

To count the number of pairs of adjacent words with the same first letter, you only need to use a single `pair` variable. Here is my suggested code:

```py
n = int(input("Enter the length of the sequence:\n"))
pairs = 0

first_word = input("Enter word 1:\n")
current_letter = first_word[0]

for i in range(n - 1):
    word = input("Enter word " + str(i + 2) + ":\n")
    first_letter = word[0]
    if current_letter == first_letter:
        pairs = pairs + 1
    else:
        current_letter = first_letter
```

Comment: in interface design, it's not reasonable to require the user to enter redundant (and possibly wrong) information to work around a program bug.  Also, this does not address the posted problem.

Comment: Hello, sorry I don't understand. Could you please explain what you mean by "enter redundant information".  From my understanding, the first word has nothing to compare to, so I suggested initializing the current letter with information from the first word. Then,  comparison of the first letter can start with second word.

Comment: Ah ... I see now.  My mistake ... I edited your answer so I would be enabled to remove my down-vote.
Still, this does not address the main problem with the code; this should be a comment.

Comment: Thanks, you're right there are some other issues with the code. I'll add some suggested code to complete my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that you count a new pair only when the letters differ.  If the last two words match, then you never count that match.  In fact, any time you have multiple consecutive matches, you count only one.  Given the input

```
who
what
where
when
how
hold
```

Your code will count only one "pair", that being the first sequence.

From your description, imply count a "pair" whenever the current start letter equals the previous one.  Speaking of which, do *not* use a value that the user could stumble across.  Fix this with an empty string for the initial value.

```
current_letter = ''
...
for ...
    if first_letter == current_letter:
        pairs += 1

print("...", pairs)
```